# Heuristics for topological sort

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

I have a number of modules connected in a **Directed Acyclic Graph**. My problem is to find an optimal execution order (minimize the total execution time). Any **topological sort** suffices for a valid solution, but the total execution time is depends on the transitions from a module to another, not just the execution time of the module. **My question is**: are there any knows heuristics for such a problem? I am writing a paper and want to reference any similar solutions.

A bit more in detail:

Having $S_a = m_1, m_2, m_3$ and $S_b = m_1, m_3, m_2$ as two valid solutions (topological sort or the graph),

the cost of the solutions are:

$c(S_a) = c(m_1) + c(m_1, m_2) + c(m_2) + c(m_2, m_3) + c(m_3)$

$c(S_b) = c(m_1) + c(m_1, m_3) + c(m_3) + c(m_3, m_2) + c(m_2)$

since each module must be executed, in practice the costs of executing the modules can be removed. and we get:

$c(S_a) = c(m_1, m_2) + c(m_2, m_3)$

$c(S_b) = c(m_1, m_3) + c(m_3, m_2)$

in my case the factor that I consider is the modules type. executing modules of the same type after each other gives us a cost of $0$ and changing types gives us a cost of $1$. If $m_1$ and $m_2$ have the same type and $m_3$ is different we have $c(S_a) = 0 + 1 = 1$ and $c(S_b) = 1 + 1 = 2$.

Any known heuristics for this problem?