# Prove that Topological sort with constraints is NP-complete

Tags: proof-explanation, np-complete

This question is a followup to: [Heuristics for topological sort](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749524/heuristics-for-topological-sort)

I have a number of modules connected in a **Directed Acyclic Graph**. My problem is to find an optimal execution order (minimize the total execution time). Any **topological sort** suffices for a valid solution, but the total execution time is depends on the transitions from a module to another, not just the execution time of the module. If the next module has the same type, executing it will have the cost $c_1$, otherwise $c_2$, $c_1 < c_2$.

A bit more in detail, having the graph

[image]

both $S_a = m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4, m_5$ and $S_b = m_0, m_2, m_4, m_3, m_1, m_5$ are valid solutions (topological sort or the graph),

the cost of the solutions are:

$c(S_a) = c_2 + c_2 + c_2 + c_2 + c_2 = 5\times c_2$

$c(S_b) = c_2 + c_1 + c_2 + c_1 + c_1 = 2\times c_2 + 3\times c_1$

So $c(S_b) < c(S_a)$, and $S_b$ is the optimal solution.

I am trying to prove that the problem is NP-complete, but I can't manage to find a good reduction.

First rewrote the problem as a decidability problem by writing it like this: 
Is there any sorting of the modules that will have the cost less then a value $V$ (as: is there any $c(S) \leq V$)?

I was thinking to reduce the 3Sat problem to mine, but I have no idea how to deal with the value $V$. Any ideas on what reductions are possible in this case?

Comment: For graph problems you should be looking for another NP-hard graph problem as the start for your reduction.  In this case Traveling Salesman seems a natural choice.

Comment: @KyleJones: I've been trying to reduce TSP or HamPath to my problem, but the thing is I have no idea how to deal with the costs. Actually even mapping the graph is preoblematic

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple reduction from Hamiltonian Path. Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph. We construct an instance of the given topological sort problem as follows:

For each vertex $v_i$ in $V$, we define a module $m_i$. We impose no restrictions on the ordering of the $m_i$, i.e.: the DAG has no edges. For each $i,j$, if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are connected by an edge in $G$, then we define the changeover costs $c_{ij} = 1$ of executing module $i$ immediately before module $j$; otherwise, we let this changeover cost be $c_{ij} = M$ for some suitably large constant $M$, e.g.: say, $M = n^{100}$ where $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$.

Now, it should be apparent that $G$ has a Hamiltonian path if and only if the constructed topological sort problem has an ordering of cost $\leq n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$.

Comment: Your problem is more general than his: with the types framework, if the changes from m1 to m2 and from m2 to m3 are small, the change from m1 to m3 must be also small. Your reduction does not work in this context as it amounts to assume that the input graph is either not connected or is a clique.